# Passing function to another component using functional React and React-Tables

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass a function to BlogTable. BlogTable contains a react-table where I pass in columns and the data.  I also want to pass in some functions so I can update the data in the table using an AJAX call.  However, it seems the props argument is not correct and my onClick() does not have a function to click on.

The error I receive is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'handleClick')
```

This is an excerpt of the code:

```
<BlogTable columns={columns}
           data={dataTable}
           handleClick={getData}
```

/>

```
export default function BlogTable({ columns, data, props }) {

const {
    ...
} = useTable({
    columns,
    data,
}, usePagination);


<button
       type="button"
       onClick={() => props.handleClick('val')} />
```

I am passing in a function as I would like to update the data table which is in the parent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in `handleClick` but have `props` defined in your BlogTable function.  `props` should be `handleClick` if you're using the destructuring {}.

```
export default function BlogTable({ columns, data, handleClick }) {

const {
    ...
} = useTable({
    columns,
    data,
}, usePagination);

<button
       type="button"
       onClick={() => handleClick('val')} />
```